# Laravel is there any better way to generate drop down

Tags: laravel

I am fetching data in dropdown of teachers nation from `nation` table using `foreach` loop and it's working fine but I don't think so if it's a best way, is there any more efficient way to do it?

Here is how I am doing it,
I have column(nation_id) in teacher table which connects nation table.

**view:**

```
<select name="pass_place" class="custom-select" >
     <option selected value="">Choose...</option>
     @foreach($nations as $nations)
         <option value="{{$nations->id}}"  {{$teacher->nation_id== $nations->id ? 'selected' : ''}} >{{$nations->nation}}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

**controller:**

```
public function create()
{
    $teachers = Teacher::all();
    $nations = nation::all();
    return view('teachers.create',compact('teachers','nations'));
}
```

**problem:**

If I have 100 more tables like area, gender or nation, I will have to write code like `$nations = nation::all();` in controller 100 times which is not a best way.

How can I generate dropdown without repeating code.

Comment: You can use this package https://github.com/omnicode/lara-form

Comment: https://github.com/omnicode/lara-form/tree/dev-3.0

Comment: Take a look at [view-composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers)

Comment: @davit my data is not repeating, i want to access  different tables.

Comment: For this case you must be use view-composer as answered @cbaconnier